# How to get token for android OAuth?

Tags: android, google-cloud-platform, oauth-2.0, google-oauth

I need to send post request to get token from here https://developers.google.com/android-publisher/authorization

[image]

But on step 4 I don't have `client_secret`

I have `code / client_id / redirect_uri` the JSON does not have it

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The most recommended mobile solution is to use AppAuth libraries, which involves these 2 steps:

- Use Authorization Code Flow (PKCE)
- Login via System Browser (Chrome Custom Tabs)

In this case the request to get a token uses a runtime code_verifier rather than a client_secret. My [blog posts and code sample](https://authguidance.com/2019/09/13/android-code-sample-overview/) may give you something to compare against, but mobile OAuth can be quite intricate.

**Google Mobile OAuth**

Google generally recommend [AppAuth for mobile logins](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/native-app). The playmarket API is just a scope value, so I see no reason why it wouldn't work.

References to client secrets in the Playmarket page may just be incomplete documentation. I haven't used this particular API but have used similar Google resources.

**Quick Next Steps I'd Recommend**

Try running the Google AppAuth sample - [this blog post of mine](https://authguidance.com/2018/02/20/android-setup) makes this very easy.

Then repoint the sample to your Google Auth Server and add the Playmarket scope. You should then get a token and be able to successfully access Playmarket resources.

If there are no problems, integrate the solution into your own app. If you run into usability problems, have a read of my blog posts.

**Coding Aspects**

Not sure what language you're using, but my [Kotlin sample code](https://github.com/gary-archer/oauth.mobilesample.android/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/authguidance/basicmobileapp/plumbing/oauth/AuthenticatorImpl.kt) uses the libraries with a modern async await syntax.

Comment: Will this solution work with google cloud infrastructure? Because I need that OAuth to get an access to the play market API

Comment: Should be fine - see my updated answer, which should enable you to verify this fairly quickly using Google's AppAuth code sample.